# ReactJS modifiying data in state

Tags: reactjs, reducers

I just starting on React, and starting to do a todo list. It has functionalities like add, modify(done/pending) and remove task.

Below is my action

```
export const ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK';
export const TOGGLE_TASK = 'TOGGLE_TASK';
export const REMOVE_TASK = 'REMOVE_TASK';
export const FILTER_TASK = 'FILTER_TASK';

let todoId = 1;

export function addTask(task) {

    let todo = {
        id: todoId++,
        name: task,
        status: 0,
        visible: true
    };

    return {
        type: ADD_TASK,
        payload: todo
    };
}

export function toggleTask(id) {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_TASK,
        payload: id
    };
}

export function removeTask(id) {
    return {
        type: REMOVE_TASK,
        payload: id
    };
}

export function filterTask(id) {
    return {
        type: FILTER_TASK,
        payload: id
    };
}
```

and my reducer :

```
import { ADD_TASK, TOGGLE_TASK, REMOVE_TASK, FILTER_TASK } from '../actions/index';

let filterStatus = -1;

//initial state is array because we want list of city weather data
export default function(state = [], action) {
    // console.log('Action received', action);

    const toggling = function (t, action) {
        if(t.id !== action)
            return t;

        return Object.assign({}, t, {
            status: !t.status
        })
    };

    const visibility = function(t, action) {
        return Object.assign({}, t, {
            visible: action === -1 ? true : t.status == action
        })
    };

    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_TASK : 
            //return state.concat([ action.payload.data ]); //in redux reducer dont modify the state, instead create a new one baesd on old one. Here concat is create a new of old one and add a new data
            return [ action.payload, ...state];
        case TOGGLE_TASK :
            return state.map(s => toggling(s, action.payload)).map(t => visibility(t, filterStatus));
        case REMOVE_TASK :
            return state.filter(s => { return (s.id != action.payload) } );
        case FILTER_TASK :
            filterStatus = action.payload;

            return state.map(t => visibility(t, action.payload));
    }
    return state;
}
```

I read somewhere that modifying state is reducer is a bad practice, yet I feel that I'm doing it in my reducer.
Could anyone suggest the correct way of handling add,remove, update value state in the reducer ?

Thank you

Comment: You're not mutating.. map, filter and array literals are all creating a new state object (new array from old array)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need two reducers: one for managing **visibility** stuff, one for **adding, toggling and removing** tasks.
so for the second part i would like do this.

```
export const ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK';
export const TOGGLE_TASK = 'TOGGLE_TASK';
export const REMOVE_TASK = 'REMOVE_TASK';

let todoId = 1;

export addTask = (text) => ({
    type: ADD_TASK,
    id: todoId++,
    text
});

export toggleTask = (id) => ({
    type: TOGGLE_TASK,
    id
});

export removeTask = (id) => ({
    type: REMOVE_TASK,
    id
});

export function todosReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_TASK : 
            return [...state, {id: action.id, text: action.text, completed: false}];
        case TOGGLE_TASK :
            return state.map(task => task.id !== action.id ? task : {...task, completed: !task.completed});
        case REMOVE_TASK :
            return state.filter(task => task.id !== action.id);
    }
    return state;
}
```